# Dealing with &#x0D in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS, I have a package that deals with dumping data from one table to another. However after the package finishes executing I notice that my column has `&#x0D` in place of carriage returns.

Below is part of the query that handles this column.

```
(select cast((text) as varchar(max)) from [table] 
where columna = x.columna for xml path (''), type)
```

Using the `type` keyword fixed this issue when I was testing this query on the SSMS.

I also encountered another error before then, where I got the message

> Column "MyColumn" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

So I had to modify the affected column to output to `Unicode Text Stream (DT_NTEXT)` in order to avoid any errors (using Unicode String will cause truncation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.value('.',nvarchar(max)')` to the end of this statement removes all the `&#x0D` that appears in the result.

Final query should like the following:

```
(select cast((text) as varchar(max)) from [table1] 
where columna = [table2].columna for xml path (''), type).value('.',nvarchar(max)')
```

This was to fix another issue I was having in SSIS when dealing with special characters and unicode.

The site containing the solution can be found [here](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path/).

Answer (score 0):

in SSIS package, i will assume that you are using `OLEDB Source` to read data from Sql server.

you can simply use the same sql query as datasource instead of using a Table name

[image]